# Providing opt-out link when sending an email directly from a contacts record

Tags: mailing, unsubscribe, opt-out

does anyone know if the "{contact.is_opt_out}" token works when sending an email directly from the contact record. On testing, I can't seem to get it to work. No link appears in the message in the email inbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

is_opt_out isn't a link, it's the privacy preference checkbox on the contact record.

I don't believe the bulk mailing link tokens are available in this context, since you're not sending bulk mail.

But you can use the checksum token to include a link to a contact profile you set up. https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/#checksum